# Android SmsProvider, what does ICC stand for?

Tags: android, sms, icc

Specifically in the com/android/providers/telephony/SmsProvider.java

what does ICC stand for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ICC stands for Integrated Circuit Card (or, smart card). In this case, it looks like they use ICC to refer to the SIM card inside the phone, which is a smart card.

Comment: Excellent thank you, so does this mean that the SMS fields/protocol are specified in the SIM card? That way a new SIM card could add/remove fields to SMS?

Answer (score 5):

ICC is for Sim messages.
See ManageSimMessages.Java inside mms/ui package which handles this.

Also see `framework/base/telephony/java/android/telephony/SmsManager.Java` where it "ICC (Integrated Circuit Card) is the card of the device. For example, this can be the SIM or USIM for GSM."